# Replace u00A0 with space google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, non-breaking-characters

I need to replace all instances of the character `u00AO` with white space.  I would like to do this without looping

```
 var rng = sheet.getDataRange();
     rng.createTextFinder('u00AO').replaceAllWith(" ");
```

It runs but does not replace the u00AO character with the whitespace in this text

Also, I think that u00AO is the same as chr(160)
This does not work either

```
rng.createTextFinder('chr(160)').replaceAllWith(" ");
```

In VBA I just do this

```
rng.Replace "u00AO", " ", 2
```

Or this

```
rng.Replace what:=Chr(160), Replacement:=" "
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `It runs but does not work`? And also, can I ask you about `u00AO`?

Comment: Try '\u00A8' ........

Comment: @cooper `\u00A8` did not work

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Do you get any error? Are you using `.findNext()`?

Comment: the function runs but no replacement takes place

Comment: @tanaite sure, please ask what ever questions you have

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry. I noticed your replying just now. But I noticed your issue had already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
function ReplaceALL() {
var ss    =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet =ss.getSheetByName("A");

 sheet.createTextFinder('\u00A0').replaceAllWith(" ");

}
```